# Delete Excel row if Listbox is selected

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I need help with my code it supposed to delete the rows in my 
 sheets once the item is selected in the listbox, it is kind of strange when I run it it didn't delete the item I selected but it deleted the one above it:

```
Private Sub clearselected()
    Dim I As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    With ListBox1
        For I = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If .Selected(I) Then
                .RemoveItem I
                With Sheets("Expenses")
                    .Rows(I + 2).EntireRow.Delete
                    .Shape("Listbox1").ControlFormat.ListFillRange = _
                        .Range("B:B").Address
                End With
            End If
            todaysDate.Text = ""
            TextBox11.Text = ""
            TextBox13.Text = ""
            TextBox12.Text = ""
            TextBox4.Text = ""
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: Delete selected]

Comment: As the ListBox Index starts at 0 and Row number starts at 1, you need to change `.Rows(I + 2).EntireRow.Delete` to `.Rows(I + 3).EntireRow.Delete`. Change `I + 2` to `I + 3`. Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you so much it works when I change it to I+3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should change `i+2` to `i+3`, because of the different starting index of the row and the `ListBox`.

However, whenever you have a problem like this, simply try some "advanced" debugging, telling you exactly what is happening:

```
With Sheets("Expenses")
    MsgBox (i + 2 & " is going to be deleted!")
    .Rows(i + 2).EntireRow.Delete 'or just .Rows(i + 2).Delete
    .Shape("Listbox1").ControlFormat.ListFillRange = _
        .Range("B:B").Address
End With
```

Thus, before deleting you will see the `MsgBox`, telling you what is going to happen. If you are not happy with it, it is easy to change `i+2` to `i+3` and etc.

Comment: You don't need `.Rows(i + 2).EntireRow.Delete` just use `.Rows(i + 2).Delete`. You need to use `EntireRow` when you reference a single cell (or Range) in a row. If you want to delete the entire row it's redundant

Comment: @ShaiRado - ok, added. :)